# Frequency Domain Signal

Tags: matlab

How do I create the following graph in MATLAB :

[image]

I have a signal which I have plotted, and I have tried to recreate the graph via Fast Fourier Transform, but I am now wondering if it is a completely different method that creates it due to not being able to replicate the image.

My signal is the blue line:

[image]

I want to decompose my signal into its harmonics and plot them in a stem plot as above, with the magnitude being apparent and the harmonics been shown at their corresponding number i.e. 1, 2, 3 ....

Comment: Can you make the question more clear? What is your signal?

Answer (score 2):

The plot you are trying to do is called `stem` plot
The general syntax of the stem is

```
stem(X,Y)
```

which plots the data sequence Y at the values specified in X.
For example

```
>> x = 0:0.5:3;
>> y = [11 0 4 0 10 0 4];
>> stem(x,y)
```

Comment: Yes, but what do I do to my original signal to get the values. i.e. Do i need to perform a FFT to my signal first and then plot that via a stem plot?

Comment: @user3190506: yes, you have to take  the fft of your original signal in order to get frequency component. It also depends, if your signal is time domain. If it already in frequency domain then do not need to take fft.

Comment: @user3190506: for only plot, it is not necessary to perform the fft. You just need to sample the continuous signal to get the discrete one.